# the hit script run for 3d objects but not 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is the script for my game.but it just works for 3d object like cube and not for 2d images in the game.how to fix it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class touchinput : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( Input.GetTouch(0).position );
            RaycastHit hit;

            if ( Physics.Raycast(Ray, out hit))
            {
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i try to change to this but i get lots of errors and don't know how to fix.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class touchinput : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            Ray2D ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( Input.GetTouch(0).position );
            RaycastHit2D hit;

            if ( Physics2D.Raycast(Ray2D, out hit))
            {
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2d and 3d physics can not interact with each other

Answer (score 2):

Raycast indeed doesn't work on 2D colliders.
I found [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/577314/how-to-detect-if-a-sprite-was-object-was-touched-i.html) method the other day, you can try it:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
    if (collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```